# Type mismatch error (vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I get  Type mismatch error in the last line of this part of code:

```
Dim test As Object
Set test = Mid(Trim(row.Cells(1, 19).Value), 9, 1) Mod 2
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no type hierarchy in VBA, an `Object` is for object instances, it cannot hold primitive types.

Use a `Long`

```
Dim test As long
test = Mid(Trim(row.Cells(1, 19).Value), 9, 1) Mod 2
```

Comment: May as well use the string function `Mid$` rather than the variant `Mid`